# results.map is not a function (Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.)

Tags: reactjs

[image]I have this what may seem like a simple problem for more experienced developers but it has been irritating me for quite a while.

I keep having .map is not a function, although it clearly is. see the code below

I am iterating over the results state, but it doesn't seem to work

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<App.js>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```js
import "./App.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ContactCard from "./ContactCard";

const App = () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setResults(data);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {results.map((result, i) => {
        return (
          <ContactCard
            key={i}
            avatarUrl={result.picture.large}
            name={result.name}
            email={result.email}
            age={result.dob.age}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const ContactCard = (props) => {
  const [showAge, setShowAge] = useState(false);
  const showAgefn=()=>{
    setShowAge(!showAge)
  }

  return (
    <div className="contact-card">
      <img src={props.avatarUrl} alt="profile" />
      <div className="user-details">
        <p>Name: {props.name}</p>
        <p>Email: {props.email}</p>
        <button onClick={showAgefn}>Show age</button>
        {showAge && <p>Age: {props.age}</p>} 
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ContactCard;
```

Comment: `data` is 99.99% not an array

Comment: I had added the picture of what I was getting, it says it is an array though

Comment: No, it's not, you have to do `data.results` to get the array

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
{results.results.map((result, i) => {
        return (
          <ContactCard
            key={i}
            avatarUrl={result.picture.large}
            name={result.name}
            email={result.email}
            age={result.dob.age}
          />
        );
}
```

i prefer to rename my state to `[data, setData]` then I can use data.results instead of `results.results`

Comment: I tried , results.results.map but still nothing but it is not showing another error, one that seems to deal with array not being an object:

Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title, first, last}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: The error means that we are trying to directly render an array or an object in our JSX code, check your object in your array maybe there is nested object that you try to render it directly

Comment: This answer won't work because the state `results` was initialized with an array type, your code has a bug

Comment: I don't know if I solved correctly, but was reading somewhere, and this syntax worked: Aslo, I changed the state to [users, setUsers]






return (
    <div>
      {Array.from(users.map((user, i) => {
        return (
          <ContactCard
            key={i}
            avatarUrl={user.picture.large}
            name={user.first}
            email={user.email}
            age={user.dob.age}
          />
        );
      }))}
    </div>
  );

Answer (score 1):

This issue is that the response you are getting from https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5 is like as follows

```json
{
   "results": [...],
   "info": {...}
}
```

So in your useEffect just modify the following

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setResults(data.results); // Just modify this line
      });
  }, []);
```

All Other things are perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

Hope it Helps

First results keyword is the state and Second results keyword is for the array.
Don't Forget to use ?.map as if the map is null it won't return any error. It's a check if there is any data in map or not.

```
{results.results?.map((result, i) => {
        return (
          <ContactCard
            key={i}
            avatarUrl={result.picture.large}
            name={result.name}
            email={result.email}
            age={result.dob.age}
          />
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Saving the state like so [users, setUsers]

Then adding Array.from inside the curly brackets seem to have solved the issue

```js
return (
    <div>
      {Array.from(users.map((user, i) => {
        return (
          <ContactCard
            key={i}
            avatarUrl={user.picture.large}
            name={user.first}
            email={user.email}
            age={user.dob.age}
          />
        );
      }))}
    </div>
  );
```